# encoding HTML error with scrapy 1.5.1 in python

Tags: python, parsing, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

So, I am scraping data from webpages in Python 3.6. After receiving the response there seems to be an error in the encoding when I try to output the data to a file.

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'example'

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://www.bdfa.com.ar/plantel-Boca-Juniors-6.html',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, encoding='utf-8')

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("-")
    # lista = response.xpath('//*[@id="navPlalist"]/li/table/tr/td/img') # will use in the future.
    filename = 'Superliga-Plantel-%s-%s.html' % (page[-3], page[-2])
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write((response.body))

execute(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'example'])
```

I tried 2 things:

First without explicit encoding (scrapy documentation says it uses UTF-8 by default), then specifically I set the encoding to UTF-8 and only some parts are properly encoded others are not.
For example `<title>Plantel de Club Atlético Boca Juniors|Equipo Actual|Lista de Jugadores</title>` this is well encoded

and this other part `<td width="50"><span class="selected" style="color:#F00;">Toda nuestra informaci&oacute;n ahora es gratuita. Agradecemos su donaci&oacute;n para continuar con nuestro proyecto, Gracias.</span></td>`
is clearly not.

if I use lxml package explicitly the parsing is done without any issues.

Thank you,
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Try `codecs` to write `utf-8` to a file

```
import codecs

file = codecs.open("lol", "w", "utf-8")
file.write(u'\ufeff')
file.close()
```

Comment: I already did, it did force the UTF 8 encoding but the HTML was still messed up.  I think there is something wrong with parser, I have also printed the output in the console before saving and the HTML is messed up too.